Can anything have permittivity and permeability less than that of vacuum?
Is it possible for something to have permittivity and permeability less than that of free space? Because space is not really truly empty as annihilation and formation of matter and antimatter continuously happens there.
In my research I found that it is not really proven that the permittivity and permeability on free space is minimum.

This question is similar to: Can relative permittivity be less than 1?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
